# How to use a custom comparer to sort elements alphabetically in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I'm trying to write a custom comparer which sorts a list of  CityInfo object alphabetically by cityname.

```
 public class CityInfoComparer 
    {
        private readonly IComparer<string> _baseComparer;

        public CityInfoComparer(IComparer<string> baseComparer) 
        {
            _baseComparer = baseComparer;
        }

        public int Compare(CityInfo city1, CityInfo city2)
        {
            return _baseComparer.Compare(city1.CityName, city2.CityName);

        }
    }


public class CityList
    {
        public List<CityInfo> CityInfos { get; set; }

        public void Sort(CityInfo city1, CityInfo city2)
        {
            CityInfos.Sort(new CityInfoComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCulture));

            //CityInfos.Sort()
        }

    }
```

I am getting an error for this line:

CityInfos.Sort(new CityInfoComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCulture));

Cannot convert from CityInfo to Systems.Generic.Collections.Icomparer

Comment: Because that method requires an object that implements `IComparer`. You need to tell it your class implements that interface

Comment: Check the following documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__      and  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c

Comment: which method are u talking about , sort or Compare ?

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit from IComparer, see below:

```
public class CityInfoComparer:IComparer<CityInfo>
{
    private readonly IComparer<string> _baseComparer;

    public CityInfoComparer(IComparer<string> baseComparer)
    {
        _baseComparer = baseComparer;
    }

    public int Compare(CityInfo city1, CityInfo city2)
    {
        return _baseComparer.Compare(city1.CityName, city2.CityName);
    }
}


public class CityList
{
    public List<CityInfo> CityInfos { get; set; }

    public void Sort()
    {
        CityInfos.Sort( new CityInfoComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCulture));
    }

}
```